# Error throw exception when insert data with thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception, unhandled-exception

I have probem when use thread in winform.
I have error when debug program.

My Application throw exception when start program.

[image: My Application throw exception when start program]

I define `class RunInUIThread` is:

```
private void RunInUIThread(Delegate method)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(method);
}
```

And in RunInUIThread method like:

```
BaiXeBUS baixe = new BaiXeBUS();
RunInUIThread(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
{
          BaiXeDTO obj = new BaiXeDTO();      //Map all to define database 
          txtKhuVucBai.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1.ToString();
          txtMaThe.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock2.ToString();

          //If I comment all below code. It's work. But I need Insert data to database.
          txtKhuVucBai.Text = obj.IDBaiXe.ToString();
          txtMaThe.Text = obj.IDRF.ToString();
          obj.BienSoXe = textBox1.Text;
          obj.HinhBienSo = color.ToString();
          obj.HinhChuXe = img.ToString();
          obj.ThoiGianVao = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
          obj.ThoiGianRa = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
          baixe.BaiXe_Insert(obj); //Contain data access layer to insert data with store procedure.
}));
```

Why my code not work. Someone can explain me and how to fix problem?
Thank all reader!!!

Comment: Temporarily you can remove the code block from `ThreadStart` and debug where the exact problem is. Starting from a different thread makes it difficult to debug so if it's possible to run it directly from main UI thread that would be best.

Comment: Take a look at  : View Detail in the message box. UI Thread _: maybe synchronization context.

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez, Thanks to suggest. When comment this line. I found error comment bellow.

Comment: Did you put this code into the form constructor? Can you see the form before this code runs? This error usually indicates that the form hasn't been created yet (you can check it using this.IsHandleCreated). Or you've closed the form and the thread finishes, tries to update the form but its disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean is trying to run this block of code without the `ThreadStart`

```
{
    BaiXeDTO obj = new BaiXeDTO();      //Map all to define database 
    txtKhuVucBai.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1.ToString();
    txtMaThe.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock2.ToString();

    //If I comment all below code. It's work. But I need Insert data to database.
    txtKhuVucBai.Text = obj.IDBaiXe.ToString();
    txtMaThe.Text = obj.IDRF.ToString();
    obj.BienSoXe = textBox1.Text;
    obj.HinhBienSo = color.ToString();
    obj.HinhChuXe = img.ToString();
    obj.ThoiGianVao = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    obj.ThoiGianRa = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    baixe.BaiXe_Insert(obj); //Contain data access layer to insert data with store procedure.
}
```

This is to debug your code within the main thread.

Comment: First, I want thank to you, @Joel lagaspi Enriquez.
Yup, I've understand. I create the new function `InsertDataToBaiXe` and put function into event `button_click`. It work. But I want it autorun.

The reason I want call InsertDataToBaiXe is: when swipe card, it check and automatic assign RFID(id of mifare card) and auto add RFID into database.

Comment: Any possiblity that you are having cross thread operation? To what I understand your code is working when not running in different thread. I am not sure if this would help but you can check how to make thread safe calls, or check this as a start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks your link provide. I create 3 thread running in 1 function. That's ok until when I using database. It's bug appear.

Answer (score 0):

@JoelLegaspiEnriquez, your recommned me to remove `[STAThread]` in Program.cs?

If I comment this line. This have problem in control AxLiveX1 is control of camera ip.

[image: Exception Error when debug]

The `txtKhuVucBai.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1.ToString();` is Guid type with 16byte: 8d58d690-6b71-4ee8-85ad-006db0287bf1.

But i assign txtKhuVucBai to Guid type is:

```
private Guid mCurrentCardIDBlock1;
public Guid CurrentCardIDBlock1
{
        get { return mCurrentCardIDBlock1; }
}
```

The mCurrentCardIDBlock1 is type of RFID reader with 32 character random.

Comment: No do not remove `[STAThread]` try removing the `ThreadStart` instead to check the exact error is. I can't put the code here as it is too long, so I placed it as answer instead.